# Javascript date in different formats

Tags: javascript

How can one get a date in the following format?

```
"Mon, May 2, 2016"
```

I have a function called  formatDate(day, month year)

I want to call it like this

```
formatDate(2,5,2016)
```

and get the previous string.

I would also like to know how to get a date in the following format:

```
May 2016
```

I would like to call it like this:

```
formatMonth(2,5,2016)
```

Comment: I guess that depends on the implementation of `formateDate`. What does it currently return? Does it allow you to specify the format?

Comment: Use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Also: [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461/218196)

Comment: function formatDate(day, month, year) {
        var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
        date = date.toDateString().split(' ');
        return date[0] + ', ' + date[1] + ' ' + Number(date[2]) + ', ' + date[3];
    }

    function formatMonth(day, month, year) {
        var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
        date = date.toDateString().split(' ');
        return date[1] + ' ' + date[3];
    }

Comment: @Waterscroll your answer is the one I was looking for!